# ColdFusion10 Developer and Windows7 (IIS7.5)

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-7.5

I am trying to learn ColdFusion and have installed the developer edition (CF10) on my Win7 computer and this brings up the localhost administrator page correctly but I have a test helloworld.cfm file in inetpub/wwwroot and when I try & access this with localhost/helloworld.cfm windows opens a dialogue box saying what program should open this .cfm file?
(in IIS Mime type there is none for .cfm & when I tried to add one it didn't work...).
Several posts on the internet say ensure IIS has CGI enabled and ISAPI Extensions
    IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility which I have. 
I'm not sure what is wrong here-can anyone advise me clearly & simply if I can view and use .cfm in IIS & how?

Comment: What happens if you put the helloworld file in the same dir as the administrator and then access it accordingly?

Comment: Hi-thanks for your quick reply-if I do as you suggest then I can view the helloworld.cfm file properly. I would like the functionality to view/use .cfm in IIS ?.....

Answer (score 1):

We know IIS is the problem because your administrator works, so CF is running correctly.

What I do is the following

1. create a site in IIS, just basic. no setting changes
2. install coldfusion 10
3. During install coldfusion will ask me if it has to configure all current IIS sites
   if you let it do that, it should all work like a charm.

Did you do it like this?

Comment: Thanks for your further helpful reply. I didn't do exactly as you state- I did not setup a new site in IIS before installing ColdFusion10 dev edition. So it will be worth uninstalling CF10 & setting up a new site in IIS before reinstalling CF10 dev edn again! I will try that & see if it will work. I'll let you know if it works.....

Comment: Yes, please do :)
I find it much easier if CF just handles the IIS stuff. If you have further questions, don't hesitate to ask

Comment: I have just tried the above uninstall/reinstall & I still get a 403 error eg:
Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found                                                                                                                                   
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.                                                                              I have to go out now & will look at it again later....

Comment: Now it sounds like the ISAPI isn't configured.. Though this should have happened through CF.

Comment: Well I'm still stuck with this (IIS7.5 opening a dialogue box saying <<< "You have chosen to open xxxx.cfm  which is a .cfm file from http://localhost What should Firefox do with this file? Open with (Browse)/FlashGot/Save File >>>> everytime I try to access .cfm)---I am grateful for any further help-thanks

Comment: I'm still trying to fix this-afaik I need to manually add Handler mappings for .cfm to my IIS7.5 but how do I do this for this CF10 dev edn?

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall and re-install as something must have gone wrong connecting IIS to COldFusion

Comment: Thanks Paul for your advice. I have already uninstalled & reinstalled ColdFusion10 (Dev edn) with no success. I wonder about the uninstall process for IIS? Do I just uncheck the boxes in the 'enable more windows program features', reboot and then recheck all the boxes and will all my files in wwwroot be unaffected? This could take a little while....

Comment: Uninstalling CF will not delete any files you create in the webroot.

Answer (score 0):

CF10 does not require the IIS 6 compatibility.  If you don't need that for any other web technology connections, then remove that.  You do need CGI, .Net Extensibility, ASP.NET, ISAPI Extensions and ISAPI Filters.  I believe the connector configurator for ColdFusion especially uses the .Net Extensibilty to "wire things up".